# Problem with MongoDB GridFS Saving Files with Node.JS

Tags: mongodb, node.js, gridfs

I have a function saving a file to gridfs.  It somehow stopped working sporadically after a refactor and I've spent over 2 hours staring blankly at it.  I swear it's roughly the same as it was.  I seem to remember it not working at first before I added close, then it started working, but it could be the insomnia.  Essentially the issue is the db.fs.files collection doesn't have any records, but chunks are getting added to db.fs.chunks.

**data** is a buffer loaded from disk via fs.readFile()

```
 31    var gs = new mongodb.GridStore(this.db, filename, "w", {
 32        "chunk_size": 1024*4,
 33        metadata: {
 34          hashpath:gridfs_name,
 35          hash:hash,
 36          name: name
 39        }
 40    });
 41    gs.open(function(err,store) {
 42       gs.write(data,function(err,chunk) {
 43          //cb(err,hash,chunk);
 44          //self.close();
 45       });
 46    });
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are a couple of solutions. You can use writeBuffer, writeFile or the new simple grid class. Under is your example adjusted for the fact of using a buffer instance.

```
// You can use an object id as well as filename now
var gs = new mongodb.GridStore(this.db, filename, "w", {
  "chunk_size": 1024*4,
  metadata: {
    hashpath:gridfs_name,
    hash:hash,
    name: name
  }
});

gs.open(function(err,store) {
  // Write data and automatically close on finished write
  gs.writeBuffer(data, true, function(err,chunk) {
    // Each file has an md5 in the file structure
    cb(err,hash,chunk);
  });
});
```

In general the best place to start are the tests that cover a wide usage profile for the gridfs classes. Look at.

https://github.com/christkv/node-mongodb-native/tree/master/test/gridstore

Comment: Actually this still does not save a file to fs.files though the collection is created and chunks are still saved.  I can't look up the file after it's written.  This is infuriating :(

Comment: It doesn't write unless close() is in the writeBuffer callback.