# Saving Files to MongoDB GridFS with Node.JS

Tags: node.js, mongodb, gridfs

How do you put the close() in the writeBuffer callback?

This question relates to:
[Problem with MongoDB GridFS Saving Files with Node.JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6936396/problem-with-mongodb-gridfs-saving-files-with-node-js)

Comment: and then I read the last comment at the bottom of this one [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8135718/how-to-use-gridfs-to-store-images-using-node-js-and-mongoose ... looks like the writeBuffer has since been deprecated. So how now?

Comment: Why don't you rewrite your question with your attempt, and updated question (instead of the comment).

Comment: oh don't just tease with a response like that... if you know the answer then please do share. 
ps. the answer I am looking for will come from a respondent recognizing the following: node.js, callback, close, mongodb, gridfs,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple example is

https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native/blob/master/test/gridstore/grid_store_test.js#L97

Also check the docs for changes in behavior, writeBuffer was removed so just use write.

http://mongodb.github.com/node-mongodb-native/

Comment: Thanks. I guess that's why I still haven't figured out how to put the close() in the writeBuffer callback, however I was able to get the desired result using a "return file.writeFile(path, fn);" as per an example I found here: https://github.com/jamescarr/nodejs-mongodb-streaming