# How to read from a raw text file using a JSON script

Tags: json, mongodb, io

I have some raw text files with words. I want to insert those words into a local collection in mongodb. How does one read from a text file using a .js script? Whilst this is probably trivial I found no clear way of reading a local text file in javascript.

Edit: Just to be clear, the text files and the database are local.

Comment: Reading file: http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html

Storing file: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14017826

Comment: Thanks for the answer. One more thing: When doing multiple upserts of initial data (2-300k), is node.js faster than pymongo and why?

Comment: I do not think one will be significantly faster than the other. You just need to give it a try.